# How can I get values from my schema in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I need status field from an object on screenshot: [BookInstanceSchema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0EV9.png)

Comment: Ok so this code works:
await BookInstance.schema.path("status").enumValues

Answer (score 0):

```
let useremail = await UserModel.findOne({ email: email });
```

Retrive the document from you collection. See the above example.

```
console.log(useremail.email);
```

This way you will get your field.

Comment: And this code didn't work for me

Comment: okay can you be more specific? what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Already solved, check my comment. Thank you anyway